# "Подозрение на что-то"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Можно ли сказать так: "этот товар снят с производства из-за подозрений..." далее следует "подозрения на содержание вредных веществ" или как? Причем, язык нужно выдержать именно канцелярско-деловой.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

ПОДОЗРЕНИЕ, 2.Предположение о возможности чего-л.; признак, намёк, дающий возможность предполагать что-л. Иметь п. на туберкулёз. При подозрении на столбняк пить спиртное воспрещено.

Это значение слова "подозрение" подходит к нашему случаю. В части содержания фразы можно было бы добавить "превышение нормы содержания вредных веществ", так как какое-то допустимое количество их всегда присутствует.

Получится:"Этот товар снят с производства из-за подозрения на превышение нормы содержания вредных веществ".